# How to change the default integer value in a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashmap

I am creating a map to compare and see if all letters of a word are unique or not. When I create this map I store the value of 1 for the corresponding character. Problem is, when I print the values of the map from the character keys I only receive zeros for all values.

While trying to research this, someone had told me this is due to all values of the map are defaulted to zero and my integer has to be initialized for it to change. I am not completely clear on what they meant by the integer needs to be initialized because I should be able to pass in a literal integer value, right?

The following is the code I currently have, as you will see I am trying to pass in 1 for the characters of the word and my code checks to see if the character already exists in the map:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <map>
    using namespace std;
    bool unique(char const* word)
      {
       map<char,int> cmpr;

       for(int i =0; word[i]!='\0';i++)
       {
         if(cmpr[word[i]])
         {
           cout<<"Not all unique";
           return false;
         }
    else
        {
             cmpr.insert(pair<char,int>(word[i],1));
        }
            cout<<cmpr[char(word[i])];
    }
    for(map<char,int>::iterator it = cmpr.begin(); it != cmpr.end();it++)
    {

        cout<<it->first<<" and "<<it->second<<endl;


    }
    return true;
}
int main()

{
    unique("hello");
}
```

**And my output results in (when trying to print first and second values of map nodes):**

```
    e and 0 
    h and 0
    l and 0
    o and 0
```

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` and not character array pointers.  One common issue with character arrays, is comparing the pointers for ordering not the target string.

Comment: When searching a `map`, prefer to use `find` than `[]`.  The `find` will not insert a new key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that

```
if(cmpr[word[i]])
```

Inserts a element into the map if one does not exist which it does not here.  That means that

```
cmpr.insert(pair<char,int>(word[i],1));
```

Is a do nothing operation since the key `word[i]` already exists.

What you can do is change the condtion to

```
if(cmpr.find(word[i]) != cmpr.end())
```

since `find` will not insert an element or change

```
cmpr.insert(pair<char,int>(word[i],1));
```

to

```
cmpr[word[i]] = 1;
```

To get it to work

---

Do note though that none of this is really necessary.  If you use a `std::sting` and a `std::set` then you entire function could be written as

```
bool unique(const std::string& word)
{
    return std::set(word.begin(), word.end()).size() == word.size();
}
```

What that does is constructs a `set` from the `string` and the `set` has the same mechanics were it only allows unique keys. This means that if the sizes are not the same then there was at least one repeated character in there.

Comment: Or fix the conditional to check whether an element exists without inserting one (`map::find()` member function)

Comment: @BenVoigt Wow.  Can't believe I forgot that.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default value with an increment:

```
if (cmpr[word[i]]++ != 0)
    // value was already present
```

This has the added bonus (depending on how you look at it) that you can get the number of occurrences of each character after the data has been added.